# How to fix an alarm event not triggering? [Gamemaker studio]

Tags: game-maker, debugging, bug

**Object_1's alarm 1 event**

```
show_message("alarm triggered");
if (Destroy = true){
    instance_destroy();
}
```

**Object_trigger's alarm start**

```
 while (!ds_stack_empty(obj_Handle_Links.Link_Stack))
      {
        temporary = ds_stack_pop(obj_Handle_Links.Link_Stack);
        temporary.Destroy = true;
        temporary.image_index = 0;
      }
        alarm[1] = 3;
```

**Comments:**

I've tried changing the alarm (and alarm event). I've tried having the `alarm[1]=3` in and out of the while loop. I've tried changing the values assigned to alarm.

No matter what I do, the alarm event just doesn't trigger. It doesn't hit the `show_message`. I just don't know what is going on.

Comment: What *Event* is `object_trigger`'s code in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alarm needs to be on the same object. When invoking `alarm` it's reading the local alarms, you would need to do `Object_1.alarm[index]` to be able to change that.

Comment: Oh, so they aren't global variables? OK. One moment. I'll test this, and if it's true, I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks. Yup. just needed that. Thanks.